# How to get local filename using URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, image, object

I am using `createObjectURL` to get an image's attributes such as width and height. How do I get the local filename?

```
loadURL = function (event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('myimage'),
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    output.onload = function () {

        document.getElementById("urlinput").value = output. ? ? ? ? ?

        document.getElementById("width").value = output.width;
        document.getElementById("height").value = output.height;
    }
}
```

How do you get the filename from this? I have tried `filename`, `src`,and `name`. I know I can get the value from the corresponding `input type="file"` but I want to get it from the object (output.????? above), but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`URL.createObjectURL` does not have any of that information in the final returned value. It returns a URL of type string. And neither would your `img` element by default but if your `event.target` is a input of type file you can get the file name from that.

```
loadURL = function (event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('myimage'),
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
        fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
    output.onload = function () {

        document.getElementById("urlinput").value = output. ? ? ? ? ?

        document.getElementById("width").value = output.width;
        document.getElementById("height").value = output.height;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/h1pswvk1/

Fiddle Code

HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="file" />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change',
    function (event) {
        alert(event.target.files[0].name);
    }
);
```

**EDIT**: Sorry I guess I missed that last part where you said you know you can get it from the input. Either way if your `document.getElementById('myimage')` is an img tag that would not have the file name. The only option would be if the `src` has the url to parse that out but from your code it seems like the `img` tag exists but has no `src` until a file is added to input and then you set the `src` programmatically. Please correct if I am wrong. Why do you not want to get it from where it is available? Why only from the `myimage` element?

Comment: I always take note of things I "should" be able to do but am not sure how to do. I am just surprised that if this object is being created from an input file that the object does not contain some reference to the file's name. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes but `URL.createObjectURL` returns a url. Not an object. It returns a string. Whatever you passed to it to create that url is not apart of the final returned value. But anyway...no problem!! You're welcome for the answer.